# Adding new polygons in shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have a file from IUCN with data of distributional polygons of frogs' species (Anura.shp). But, this shapefile doesn't have all the species that I need. So, I looked for additional data and I got some csv files with points from other species. I would like to create new polygons in the Anura.shp with these csv files.

Comment: Does csv include point or polygon coordinates and how?

Comment: The csv includes point coordinates.

Comment: Your question is not clear. How do you make new polygons from points? I mean, what is the relationship between the points to construct polygons? Can you clarify a little more? Can you share a sample CSV?

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect the points using [Points to path](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#qgispointstopath). Your point layer must have an attribute field to select as `Order expression`. If the points belong to more then one polygon, use the `Path group expression`. Check the box next to `Create closed paths`.
2. Run `Menu Vector / Geometry Tools / Lines to Polygons`
3. Select all the polygons created in step 2, copy and paste them to the initial polygon layer.